# @Input decorator and Karma tests

Tags: angular, karma-webpack

After excluding some components' parts into smaller UI-components I assigned them properties which are passed from parent and got with help of `@Input()` decorator. But it looks like Karma doesn't understand these Inputs and throws me errors like

> Can't bind to 'property' since it isn't a known property of 'app-component'.
>
> 1. If 'app-component' is an Angular component and it has 'property' input, then verify that it is part of this module.

Comment: Show us your test. Most likely you didn't configure your test module properly

Comment: I run basic tests which are created by default Angular CLI command.

Comment: Why are you using input property on the root component?

Comment: It's not the root. I just renamed component and property for that site.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your testing module correctly

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [FormsModule],
      declarations: [AppComponent, yourComponent ..etc]
    });
  });
```

Comment: I don't have any forms on my site

Comment: its just a sample code, you need to import whatever the module components you are using it

Comment: I don't use any module but app.module which is just uniting my app.